# How to Change the Color of the typography with a certain condition

Tags: reactjs

I am new to using Material UI with `ReactJS`, and trying to change the color of typography.

I don't know where to start.
like I want to turn the text into the color **red** if the text is equal to **Not Available** and **green** if **Available**

```html
<Typography variant="h6" color="Red">{item.Product_Status}</Typography>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
color={item.Product_Status == 'available' ? return('green') : return('red') }
```

I dont know if the statement like that is correct but basically if you swap the double quotes for brackets you can run a js function inside the color property